# How to shear along edges?

Tags: modeling

**Straight to the point.**

How can I shear along edges?

**IMAGE 1.** Shows that normal shear don't work.

**IMAGE 2.** Is my desired output. Kinda like CTRL + SHIFT + S but along edges.

[image: Normal shear don't work.]

[image: Desired output.]

**EDIT:** For clarity.

**IMAGE 3:** Shear works perfectly when the mesh is either perfectly horizontal or vertical.

**IMAGE 4:** It doesn't anymore when the edges of the mesh are diagonal or tilted.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello. I _think_ I get what you mean, but can't be sure. Maybe you could make this clearer by illustrating the state of the mesh _before_ your move to the desired result.

Comment: I added some information just to clarify. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Basically what I want to know is that whether there is a way to shear it "along the edges" instead of manually having to select the edge and slide them.

Comment: Shear will move the vertices on the X or Y axis of your view, that's how it works, could you please show a drawing of the before and after that you would like to see?

Comment: Hello @moonboots, I attached an image above stating the results I want.

Comment: You can change the space Shear works in.. for example to the 3D cursor, (which you can snap to face-normal) But it's a few steps, and I can't immediately think of the use-cases, when GG on either end would do, relatively quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select one of the edges that the vertices are going to move along with the Normal selection type and hit the + icon it will save that orientation.
[image]

You can then select the edge and shear it using that orientation

[image]

Alternatively, without having to set up the transform orientation and/or if you want to shear it when it's intersecting multiple other edges that are not parallel, I think you'd need an add-on like machin3tools. It lets you slide loops like that along the geometry. I don't think there's a way to natively do this in blender.
[image]
https://youtu.be/KOecgIbBRLE?t=116